# C using scanf() on Strings

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, scanf

Basically I want to scanf "strings" from a text file and pass them through to another method (that does array stuff). **The current method I have works**, but because I don't know the size of the potential input, I have to allocate a ridiculous amount of memory for any sized string (repeating this free and allocating process until there are no more items to be read)
Is there a more eloquent solution to what I already have?

```
int main(void) {
char *item;
item = emalloc(100000 * sizeof *item);
flexarray my_flexarray = flexarray_new();

while (1 == scanf("%s",item)) {
    flexarray_append(my_flexarray, item);
    free(item);
    item = emalloc(100000 * sizeof *item);
}
free(item);

flexarray_print(my_flexarray);
flexarray_free(my_flexarray);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What is `flexarray` and `emalloc`? Did you compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`)? Did you use the debugger `gdb`  and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: This is a repeated question from *How to prevent scanf causing a buffer overflow in C?* as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/how-to-prevent-scanf-causing-a-buffer-overflow-in-c

The answer of how to dynamically allocate memory from scanf is listed in the man page on `scanf`: *EXAMPLE To use the dynamic allocation conversion specifier, specify m as a length modifier (thus %ms or %m[range]).*

Comment: I usually use a recursive function I wrote which basically allocates reasonably-sized chunk of memory in each subcall, hitting the deepest recurse when the end of the string is found, then allocate a single buffer of the correct *total* length, then when returning upwards through each call, copy the chunk in each level into the right place in the final, longer buffer.   I wouldn't do that in the kernel, and I'm used to linux hosts with logical memory disabled - so malloc actually fails when no memory's left - but I'm pretty happy with it.

Comment: Your question is basically extremely good! I wish i could give you a proper answer but unfortunately i can't because stack overflow gives the power to people who are amateurs on programming to lock answers. So lets start. There are several things that must be pointed out here. First of all you have 2 types of storing. The long term and the short term. As you realised yourself using malloc in your situation is a bad idea. The reason is because malloc (the heap) should only be used in the cases you want to store something long term.

Comment: In your situation you should use the stack! You also don't want the memory to be active from the beginning of your program until the end so you should do it inside a function.